# Multithreading PyQT and job scheduler: WARNING: QApplication was not created in the main() thread

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyqt

I want to develop a job scheduler with a GUI using Python. So I have programmed a GUI (which works) and now I want to program the job scheduler to run a job after another job finishes. So the scheduler has to monitor the process of the job. When the job is finished, then the next job starts. The scheduler runs in parallel with the GUI. All jobs are set in the GUI.

My code:

```python
class Window(QWidget):
    # a lot of Code here       
        
      
class GUI(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name= name
        self.counter= counter
        
    def run(self):
        print(datetime.datetime.now())
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        w = Window()
        sys.exit(app.exec())

class JobScheduler(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name= name
        self.counter= counter
            
    def Scheduler(self):
        # Code of scheduler
        
th1 = GUI(1, "GUI", 1)
th2 = JobScheduler(2, "JobScheduler", 2)

th1.start()
th2.start()
    
while 1:
    pass
```

**The challenge:**
Only the GUI thread runs and I get so following error/warning:

> WARNING: QApplication was not created in the main() thread.

How can I fix it and why does only the GUI thread start?

Comment: Why are you creating *QApplication* in another thread?

Comment: Because I want to run the GUI in parallel to the backend.

Comment: What I mean is: why don't you create the QApplication on the main thread? Are you going to use the main thread for something else? It's not clear. I get the point of running another thread to execute tasks on the background, but the GUI thread should be on the main one.

Comment: Okay first of all, I am glad for your help. I unterstand not so much. Do you mean, that the GUI class is useless and I put the code of GUI.run before the line ```th2 = JobScheduler(2, "JobScheduler", 2)``` ?

Comment: No. I mean you're going to get lots of errors if you instantiate QApplication on another thread. You should instantiate `app = QApplication(sys.argv)` in the place of your `while 1: pass` loop. Then, call `app.exec()` right there.

Comment: Okay, I code this: ```app = QApplication(sys.argv)
th1=threading.Thread(target=JobScheduler, args=(1, "GUI", 1,))
w = Window()
th1.start()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Just to reiterate: The `QApplication` instance and all GUI elements (`QWidget`s etc.) *must* be created on the same thread as that on which `main` is running.  Doing otherwise is -- as far as I'm aware -- unsupported.